# EntityFramework migration: AlterColumn DateTime to DateTimeOffset

Tags: entity-framework, datetimeoffset, alter-column

In "Code First" EF approach, I've changed the type of a property:

Before:

```
 DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

After:

```
 DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
```

And then I executed (Package Manager Console):

```
Add-Migration Foo
```

Which created this code:

```
public partial class Foo : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Foos", "Date", c => c.DateTimeOffset(nullable: false, precision: 7));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Foos", "Date", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
    }
}
```

But this is not working when executing the update (Package Manager Console):

```
Update-Database
```

Error:

> Error Number:5074,State:1,Class:16 The object
>   'DF__Foo__2B2A60FE' is dependent on column 'Date'.
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Date failed because one or more objects
>   access this column.

How can I solve this? I'm not referencing this column in other parts (there are no indexes)

Comment: This sounds like `not null` constraint. What EF version are you on? Looks like it's fixed in the latest EF 6.2 (when I execute `Update-Database -Verbose`, I see a code for removing the constraint which seems to be missing in your case)

Comment: I'm using EF 6.1.3. Should I try the `Update-Database` with EF 6.2 ?

Comment: You were right. I updated EF and then `Update-Database` worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ivan Stoev said in the comments, this is fixed by updating to EF 6.2 (I was using EF 6.1.3)