# EF Core 6 Issue: SYSTEM_TIME period is already defined on table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-6.0

I am converting an existing set of SQL Server temporal tables to use the EF Core 6 native support for temporal tables. I am using a code-first approach. When I run `Add-Migration`, I get a migration looking like this:

[image: Generated Migration]

When I now run `Update-Database`, I get this error:

> SYSTEM_TIME period is already defined on table 'dbo.User'.

From looking for an answer, I see several SQL answers that use `IF EXISTS` to wrap `ALTER` statements. Is there a way to do this using a code-first approach in .NET Core 6?

I updated our code base to automatically support temporal tables and I then generated a migration to see if anything changed. I got a migration (shown in screenshot, truncated for space) with `AlterTable` and `AlterColumn` for the temporal tables. When I ran `Add-Migration`, I got an error:

> SYSTEM_TIME period is already defined on table 'dbo.User'

I would like to be able to use the native out of the box support for temporal tables in EF Core 6.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data only paste as text

Comment: What version of EF are you using?  Similar issue was solved by updating EF version : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027970/entityframework-migration-altercolumn-datetime-to-datetimeoffset

Comment: EF Core 7.0.2 is the version we are using. Temporal Support was added in EF Core 6.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of studying I figured out an answer that worked. In the UP section of the migration I disabled System Versioning on the table:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql($"ALTER TABLE dbo.User SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF)");
```

Then, also in the UP section, I Dropped the System_Time Period for the table :

```
migrationBuilder.Sql($"ALTER TABLE dbo.User DROP PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME");
```

I placed these statements above the auto generated migration. Then I ran Update-Database and the migration was successfully applied. This method enabled me to keep the original history tables so there was no data loss.